# My DependencyProvider for Spryker Yves does not setup dependencies

Tags: php, spryker

Spryker Kernel Exception Container does not contain the called "XXX" You can fix this by adding the key "XXX" to your "ModuleNameDependencyProvider"

ModuleNameDependencyProvider code:

```
<?php

use Pyz\Client\AddressAutocomplete\AddressAutocompleteClient;

class ModuleNameDependencyProvider extends AbstractBundleDependencyProvider
{
    public const MODULE_NAME_CLIENT = 'MODULE_NAME_CLIENT';

    /**
     * @param Container $container
     *
     * @return Container
     * @throws FrozenServiceException
     */
    public function provideServiceLayerDependencies(Container $container): Container
    {
        $container = $this->provideModuleNameClient($container);

        return $container;
    }

    /**
     * @throws FrozenServiceException
     */
    public function provideModuleNameClient(Container $container): Container
    {
        $container->set(static::MODULE_NAME_CLIENT, function (Container $container) {
            return new ModuleNameClient();
        });

        return $container;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In this case (for Yves) wrong setup dependencies method call.
I should call provideDependencies(Container $container) instead of provideServiceLayerDependencies(Container $container).

For different layers should be used different parents classes and different methods to setup dependencies:

- Yves Spryker\Yves\Kernel\AbstractBundleDependencyProvider;
- Client Spryker\Client\Kernel\AbstractDependencyProvider;
- Zed Spryker\Zed\Kernel\AbstractBundleDependencyProvider;
- Service Spryker\Service\Kernel\AbstractBundleDependencyProvider;
- Glue Spryker\Glue\Kernel\AbstractBundleDependencyProvider;

---

- Yves provideDependencies(Container $container)
- Client provideDependencies(Container $container)
- Zed provideBusinessLayerDependencies(Container $container)
- Service provideServiceDependencies(Container $container)
- Glue provideDependencies(Container $container)

May be it will be changed in future: check vendors to be sure.